# MS SQL Округление к ближайшему чётному

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть у меня логика в приложении на c#, которую я был вынужден начать дублировать на slq server в представлениях и хранимках и столкнулся с тем, что расчёт происходит различным образом.

Наглядный пример. Некоторая сущность с полем типа decimal, Code First, табличка на SQL Server, тип [тоже](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) decimal.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В C# [Math.Round](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-2.1#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_) в случае числа с половинкой округляет данные к ближайшему чётному числу (MidpointRounding.ToEven):

```
decimal val1 = 766.5m;
decimal val2 = 767.5m;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(766.5m)); // 766
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(767.5m)); // 768
```

При этом [ROUND](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) в SQL таких настроек не поддерживает:

```
DECLARE @val1 decimal = 766.5;
DECLARE @val2 decimal = 767.5;
SELECT ROUND(@val1,  0); -- 767
SELECT ROUND(@val2,  0); -- 768
```

Каким образом сделать поведение ROUND в MS SQL таким же, как в c#?

PS Версия сервера: MSSQL2016 (13.0.1601.5), .net core 2.1

Comment: SQL CLR -- не вариант: сервер не мой, а хостера -- поэтому доступ весьма урезанный.

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/bankers-rounding-in-t-sql-like-math-round-in-net

Comment: Ну и вот, для произвольного количества знаков после запятой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355763/10235013

Comment: Тут по моему наиболее точно отвечено:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592666/tsql-rounding-vs-c-sharp-rounding

Comment: скалярная функция не вариант?

Comment: @teran Видимо это самый лучший вариант, раз ничего подходящего из готового нет.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно так:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (col decimal(18,2))

INSERT @T (col)
VALUES (-122), (-122.5),
       (-123), (-123.5),
       (-124), (-124.5),
       (122), (122.5),
       (123), (123.5),
       (124), (124.5)

SELECT col
      ,IIF(CEILING(col) % 2 = 0, CEILING(col), FLOOR(col))
  FROM @T
```

Функция [CEILING](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - возвращает наименьшее целое число, большее или равное переданному в неё числовому выражению;

Функция [FLOOR](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - возвращает наибольшее целое число, меньшее или равное переданному в неё числовому выражению.

В выражении `CEILING(col) % 2 = 0` мы проверяем число с откинутой дробной частью на чётность (остаток от деления на 2 должен быть равен нулю). Если число чётное, то берём наименьшее целое, в противном случае наибольшее целое.

Конструкцию IIF так же можно заменить на CASE для версий SQL меньше 2012, которые не поддерживают IIF:

```sql
CASE CEILING(col) % 2 WHEN 0 THEN CEILING(col) ELSE FLOOR(col) END
```

P.S. Запихивать эту конструкцию в функцию я бы не стал. Вообще в SQL Server от функций лучше держаться подальше без крайней нужды, так как они могут представлять собой подводные камни в плане производительности запросов.

Comment: Да, конкретно для моего варианта вполне хватит и такого, потому что у меня чётко ограничена потребность в том, чтобы округлять до рубля. В более общем случае -- нужна более общая формула. Насчёт функций могу сказать, что вынесение в функцию способствует читаемости, чтобы не ломать голову над лишней сложностью, поэтому эта часть дискуссионная. Конкретно у меня там уже формула из трёх слагаемых, каждый из которых -- это произведение пары-тройки параметров, все три слагаемых умножаются на ещё одно число, потом идёт ToEvenRouble и потом всё это суммируется. Бррр. Я просто в вопросе сильно упростил